# How to use a vector of strings to call dataframe columns by its header

Tags: string, r, header, dataframe, cbind

In R, I want to use a subset of a dataframe 'RL', by selecting specific headers (eg. 'RL$age01' etc.. I generate the selected headers as a vector of strigs:

```
v = c('ID', sprintf("sex%02d", seq(1,15)), sprintf("age%02d", seq(1,15)))
```

and the dataframe index as:

```
c = sprintf('RL$%s', v)
```

how can I evaluate these strigns to call the dataframe columns by header and rearange them in a matrix, in the sense of x = cbind(RL$ID, RL$age01, ...) ?
cbind(c) does not work neither using things like eval(), parse() or expression().

Thanks for any help

Rafael

Comment: You can['t do that with `$` - see http://stackoverflow.com/a/18228613/1478381 for more info. Use e.g. `RL[ , 'age01' ]` for your column name, or just `RL[ , v ] ` will work given your data above.

Answer (score 1):

Just use

```
RL[,v]
```

Just noticed this was already mentioned in the comments.